# How to change the vertical position of the text in a frametitle

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

I'm wondering how to change the vertical position of the text in a frametitle? Take for instance this frametitle:

[image]

I'd like to place the text, in this case "Introduction", a bit higher such that it is exactly in the vertical center.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}

%remove navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\definecolor{TUeRed}{RGB}{170,0,0}
\definecolor{TUeBlue}{RGB}{0,68,170}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{% 
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(.95\textwidth,-1cm) \tikz {\fill[white] (0,0) -- %
(2cm,0) -- (2cm,1.1cm) -- (0.5cm,1.1cm) -- cycle;\node[TUeBlue] at %
(0.8cm,0.5cm) {\normalsize\insertpagenumber};} \end{textblock*} }

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=TUeRed}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Introduction}
Some text
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**[Edit]** Changed the LaTeX code, thanks @Percusse!

Comment: As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: Can you put a working example with two slides? I don't know where to obtain the `textblock` environment.

Comment: Which beamer theme are you using? Please add to your question a complete, minimal example (with only those relevant settings) of your document settings.

Comment: @percusse, it's from the *textpos* package. I'll add a working example. Gonzalo, I don't use a theme, I'm trying to create my own.

Comment: Just to clarify the code I replaced your template declarations with the following: `\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(.95\textwidth,-1cm)
\tikz {\fill[white] (0,0) -- (2cm,0) -- (2cm,1.1cm) -- (0.5cm,1.1cm) -- cycle;\node[TUeBlue] at (0.8cm,0.5cm) {\normalsize\insertpagenumber};}
\end{textblock*}
}`. (Using `tikz` package)

Comment: @percusse, very nice! I didn't know enough TikZ to do it like this.

Comment: Actually, a few years ago I did my Delft template using TU/e template so you can also start reading the inner theme file of the template. Or why not using it directly? ;).

Comment: @percusse, I don't want to use it because it's much too complex for what it does; obviously it's possible to create the same looks using only a few lines of LaTeX and TikZ :)

Comment: Hmm, adding `\addtolength{\topmargin}{-1mm}` seems to move the entire frametitle upwards. Now my text is vertically centered, but of course the height of the frametitle is less. Is there perhaps a way to change the margin/padding _inside_ the frametitle?

Comment: A look into the `beamer` sources ([`beamerouterthemedefault.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemedefault.sty), ll. 140-160) shows that the off-centering of the frame title is caused by inserted `\strut`s (l. 150). If they were removed, the frame title would be exactly vertically centered. I strongly advise you, however, not to do that - different frame titles with different heights would wiggle around vertically, which would look rather horrible in a presentation!

Comment: @diabonas: Can you provide an answer please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A look into the beamer sources ([`beamerouterthemedefault.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/outer/beamerouterthemedefault.sty), ll. 140-160) shows that the off-centering of the frame title is caused by inserted `\struts` (l. 150). If they were removed, the frame title would be exactly vertically centered. I strongly advise you, however, not to do that - it would either cause the height of the colored frame title box to change for different frame titles, or the title would wiggle around vertically (if you set the box to a fixed height). Both would look rather horrible in a presentation...

If you feel that all frame titles are a little too low and you want to raise them just a tiny bit, you can try something like

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip-0.5ex}{}
```