# Is it possible to reduce the height of the frame title box in beamer?

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I am writing a presentation with Beamer using the Copenhagen theme and the `\useoutertheme[footline=institutetitle]{miniframes}` option. Currently the headers look like this
[image: frame header]
but since I am not going to use frame subtitles I would like to reduce the height of the frame title box. Is this possible?

The only relevant piece of information I could find is [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52059/27664) which suggests the use of `\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip-0.5ex}{}`.
Sadly, this doesn't work for me, because it moves up the frame title box, covering part of the subsection title.

---

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Copenhagen}
  \useoutertheme[footline=institutetitle]{miniframes}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}

\begin{frame}{Baz}
  Foobar
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @samcarter Is this better?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can reduce the size by defining our own custom `frametitle`. Just play around with the values for `ht=2.0ex` and `dp=0.6ex` and tune them according to your needs.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Copenhagen}
  \useoutertheme[footline=institutetitle]{miniframes}
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.0ex,dp=0.6ex]{frametitle}
        \hspace*{1ex}\insertframetitle%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Bar}

\begin{frame}{Baz}
  Foobar
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]